# Model overfits when you don't have much varied data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to understand why it is that a model overfits when you have little data to run with.

I get the typical artistic idea behind it whereby you would essentially have the model "memorize" whatever little data (or variations to be specific) you've given it.

But is there a more robust reason for this?

Couldn't you for example with a small dataset (or large one) with very little variation, just force it to not overfit by constraining the model or adding some form of regularization?

P.S I have seen an explanation detailing how not introducing the type of variance that exists within the population can definitely lead the model to generalize less and less. But is this just a quick way to rationalize it or is there, again as i mentioned above, a way to eliminate this lack of variance in the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can add regularization, batch normalization or even dropout to reduce overfitting. model overfit when you have to less data as compared to number of parameters in models such as weights in neural network.

Also you can fix error of model in batches rather then individual sample that way your model is less likely overfit the data.

You can also add noise to data to reduce overfitting.